# NPM throwing missing but exists - only a problem one machine

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, webpack-4, npm-start, react-tabs

I have a repo (React, Webpack4, npm, babel) which installs & runs fine on my machine (original and fresh clone) but when pulled down to another machine it throws an error on `npm start` (after successfully runnning `npm install`.

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-tabs' in XXX`

The dependency in question `react-tabs` is installed in `node_modules` on both machines.

> ERROR in ./src/containers/PAGE.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-tabs' in
>   '/home/Repos/PROJECT/src/containers'  @
>   ./src/containers/PAGE.js 11:0-58 9095:88-92
>   9095:120-127 9095:155-158 9099:38-41 9103:34-37 9107:35-38 9111:39-42
>   9115:37-40 9115:74-77 9115:182-190 9119:27-35 9123:27-35 9127:27-35
>   9131:27-35 9135:27-35 9135:64-72  @ ./src/App.js  @ ./src/index.js  @
>   multi ./src/index.js Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
>        1 asset
>       Entrypoint undefined = ./index.html
>       [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html]
>   574 bytes {0} [built]
>       [./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js] 528 KiB {0} [built]
>       [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
>       [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built] ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to
>   compile.

Comment: maybe a stupid question but did you do `npm install` before you ran `npm start`? If you did and it still doesn't work you can remove your node modules and install again to see if that works. You would do `rm -rf node_modules` in the root of your directory. then `npm install` then `npm start`

Ignore that. This looks it's not found in that specific component. Are you using that package in another component? Or just `PAGE.js`?

Comment: yes we did - never a stupid question.
The package is used just in that component currently but npm start works fine on 2 other machines

Comment: did you npm start / install in the root of your project not /home? maybe it's looking for `react-tabs` in `/home`?? maybe check to see that your node_modules are in `PROJECT` and not home...

Comment: hi Ben, I've been assured that both are being run in the root - they've done the same on another machine in parallel and was fine so I believe it's not a repo thing but a system issue. Can't understand what though.